# Stop Microsoft Word from automatically opening .docx files downloaded through Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-word-2013, file-download, docx

I recently installed the Microsoft Office 2013 bundle on my computer. Since installing that, whenever I download any file Word is set up as the default program for (.docx, .doc, etc) through Google Chrome, word immediately launches and opens the file. When downloading other files, the file appears in the download bar at the bottom of the screen, which is what I would like to happen with all files. Automatically opening any file I download over the internet is generally a bad idea from a security standpoint, and .docx files have had their share of security vulnurabilities in the past.

Answer (score 2):

You must have inadvertently clicked "Always open files of this type" for one of your previously downloaded docx documents:

[image]

To stop this behavior

- go to [chrome://settings/](http://chrome://settings/)
- Expand Advanced Settings section
- Click "Clear auto-opening settings" under Downloads section

[image]

Comment: This solution doesn't work anymore on recent Chrome versions. The Advanced Settings section doesn't exist anymore. The "Clear auto-opening settings" button doesn't exist anymore, or at least I can't find it anywhere. I'm on Chrome v116.

Answer (score 0):

From Chrome menu, select Settings, select Advanced Settings, under Downloads - clear defaults.